# jQuery range slider is not working in reactJS

Tags: jquery, reactjs, integration

I have included jQuery and used this in my react but nothing worked. What am I missing?

```
ComponentDidMount() {
    $("#range-slider").jRange({
        from: 0,
        to: 100,
        step: 1,
        format: '%s',
        width: 300,
        showLabels: true,
        isRange : true
    });
},
```

```html
<input type="hidden" className="range-slider" id ="range-slider" ref="slider" value="23,70" />
```

Comment: You're missing the `function` keyword at least. What errors are there in the console? Have you included the `jRange` library script in your page?

Comment: yes i included. no error is showing

Comment: iam having one more doubt also?

Comment: how to integrate and use jquery and bootstrap with reactjs

Comment: Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: there is any DOM for range sliders like <input type="range"/>?